# How to get Vue 3 render function h() to output html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 render function and cannot work out how to render HTML in the template.

I have tried this:

```
h('span', {}, '<strong>Bold</strong>');
```

But it outputs the html tags `<strong>Bold</strong>` on the page rather than **Bold**.

Does anyone know how to get the render function to render HTML?

Comment: the first argument is the html (span in this case)

Comment: thanks @maembe, I understand that, however, what if I want it's content to be html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [h() arguments](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments),I think the render function could not render HTML directly in the children argument, you need to transfer to another render function like

```
return h('span', {}, [h('strong', 'Bold')]);
```

But you could set `innerHTML` in the props argument to make it:

```
return h('span', {
    
    innerHTML:'<strong>Bold</strong>'
    
},[]);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Ryan. innerHTML works perfectly for me as the value will come from CMS db.

Comment: @CUGreen And how to render that in the component?

Comment: @JosuéMartínez, you would do that in the `render ()` function of the component. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#declaring-render-functions

Comment: The problem is that I have dynamic objects and it exports the object to be able to render it in my html, something like:


const components = {
       button: h('button'),
       a: h('a', { ... })
};

return { components }